# Unexpected behavior with my token function

Tags: c, linux, shell, strtok

I am trying to write a simple Shell in C. Eventually, I will implement forking of processes and piping etc.  But, right now, I'm just trying to get all the logic worked out.

I have a partially working shell: When I type exit it exits... however, my token function doesn't seem to be working right.

What am I doing wrong here? I'm not sure why its seg-faulting.

`Token` prints out once in the `while` loop and then it seg-faults and crashes.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define MAX_BUF_SZ 1024

void checkForPipe(char *string, bool *pipe_bool);
void checkForRedirect(char *string, bool *redirect_bool);
void tokenizeInput(char *string, bool pipe, bool redirect);
int main()
{
    char *ptr;
    bool is_pipe = 0;
    bool is_redirect_out = 0;
    bool is_exit = 0;

    ptr = (char*)malloc(MAX_BUF_SZ);

    while(!is_exit)
    {
        // Diplay prompt
        char cur_dir[MAX_BUF_SZ];
        getcwd(cur_dir, MAX_BUF_SZ);
        printf("SHELL:%s$ ", cur_dir);

        fgets(ptr, MAX_BUF_SZ, stdin);
        checkForPipe(ptr, &is_pipe);
        checkForRedirect(ptr, &is_redirect_out);
        printf("pipe flag = %d\n", is_pipe);
        printf("redirect flag = %d\n", is_redirect_out);
        if(strcmp(ptr, "exit\n") == 0)
        {
            is_exit = 1;
        }

        tokenizeInput(ptr, is_pipe, is_redirect_out);

    }

    return 0;

}

void checkForPipe(char *string, bool *pipe_bool)
{
    char *check_for_pipes;
    char *clean_compare;
    check_for_pipes = (char*)malloc(MAX_BUF_SZ);
    clean_compare = (char*)malloc(MAX_BUF_SZ);

    strcpy(check_for_pipes, string);
    strcpy(clean_compare, string);

    char * token = strtok(check_for_pipes, "|");

    if(strcmp(token, clean_compare) == 0)
        {
         free(clean_compare);
         free(check_for_pipes);
        }

    else
    {
        *pipe_bool = 1;
        free(clean_compare);
        free(check_for_pipes);
    }
}

void checkForRedirect(char *string, bool *redirect_bool)
{
    char *check_for_redirects;
    char *clean_compare;
    check_for_redirects = (char*)malloc(MAX_BUF_SZ);
    clean_compare = (char*)malloc(MAX_BUF_SZ);

    strcpy(check_for_redirects, string);
    strcpy(clean_compare, string);

    char * token = strtok(check_for_redirects, ">");

    if(strcmp(token, clean_compare) == 0)
        {
         free(clean_compare);
         free(check_for_redirects);
        }

    else
    {
        *redirect_bool = 1;
        free(clean_compare);
        free(check_for_redirects);
    }

}

void tokenizeInput(char *string, bool pipe, bool redirect)
{
    char *copy_string;
    copy_string = (char*)malloc(MAX_BUF_SZ);

    strcpy(copy_string, string);

    if(pipe == 0 && redirect == 0)
    {
        char  **args = {NULL};
        char *token = strtok(copy_string, " ");
        int i = 0;
        printf("%s\n", token);
        while(token != NULL)
        {
            args[i] = token;
            strtok(NULL, " ");
            printf("%s\n", token);
            i++;
        }
    }
    /* printf("%s\n%s\n%s\n", args[0], args[1], args[2]); */
}
```

Comment: Use a debugger. At a minimum you should get the exact line of code that triggers the seg fault and post it in your question. You can also use the debugger to examine the state to look for suspicious values and behaviours.

Comment: `char  **args = {NULL};` That's not going to work. It's not an appropriately sized array. You need an array that is at least big enough to store all the tokens.

Comment: `char  **args` is a *Single pointer to pointer to* `char` -- it is just one pointer to a block of memory holding more pointers or `NULL` (not an array of them). As with any pointer, you must ensure it points to valid memory that you have assigned to the pointer. (at this point that is none -- meaning it's just a pointer to `NULL` at this point.) `args[i]` dereferences the `NULL` pointer so BAM!! SegFault!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is on `args[i]`
I modified your code as follows:

Supposing you have a pre-known number of token which is `MAX_BUF_SZ`.
You allocate MAX_BUF_SZ pointers of type `char*`

```cpp
 char **args = malloc(MAX_BUF_SZ * sizeof(char *));
```

and in the loop, you still have to allocate each pointer `char*` before using it:

```cpp
while(token != NULL)
 {
            args[i] = (char *)malloc(strlen(token)+1);
            printf("%s\n", token);
            args[i] = token;
            token = strtok(NULL, " ");
            i++;
  }
```

The whole functions is like this:

```cpp
void tokenizeInput(char *string, bool pipe, bool redirect)
{

    char *copy_string;
    copy_string = (char*)malloc(MAX_BUF_SZ);

    strcpy(copy_string, string);
    // suppose we would have MAX_BUF_SZ tokens
    char **args = malloc(MAX_BUF_SZ * sizeof(char *));
    if(pipe == 0 && redirect == 0)
    {
        char *token = strtok(copy_string, " ");
        int i = 0;
        //printf("token %s\n", token);

        while(token != NULL)
        {
            args[i] = (char *)malloc(strlen(token)+1);
            printf("%s\n", token);
            args[i] = token;
            token = strtok(NULL, " ");
            i++;
        }
    }
    /* printf("%s\n%s\n%s\n", args[0], args[1], args[2]); */
}
```

Here is my example running :

```sh
SHELL:D:\Users\T0180694\Documents\Mes Outils Personnels\PAN\PAN_folder$ test is essai of you and me
pipe flag = 0
redirect flag = 0
test
is
essai
of
you
and
me
```

Comment: That's a whole lot of pointers -- but at least they are valid pointers `:)`